# Website looks bigger and there are vertical lines in pictures when it is opened in Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: internet-explorer, nivo-slider

I'm developing a website for a customer:

http://alexchen.info/formatron/

[image]

He said the website looks bigger (the whole website, like from 940px wide to 1000px wide) and there are vertical lines in the pictures (jQuery Nivo Slider):

(There are in fact vertical lines).

I took a snapshot using Adobe Browser Lab:

[image]

But everything looks normal (don't mind the height of the image, I changed it).

Does it look OK in your computers? What can be causing this?
(I think my customer has is web browser zoomed in, but I can't explain the vertical lines).

Comment: I was able to reproduce a similar effect in IE8 by using View > Zoom. Otherwise it looked fine.

Comment: @twsaef so the vertical lines only appear when it is zoomed in?

Comment: Yes. Zooming in caused vertical lines to appear similar to what is in your screenshot.

Comment: @twsaef Thanks, do you want to post an answer so I can tick it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce a similar effect in IE8 by using View > Zoom in.

Answer (score -1):

Please try to reduce the number of 'slices' in the nivoSlider setup.